# Call static properties within another class in php

Tags: php, oop, static, dynamic-variables, late-static-binding

I have problem about calling a static property of a class inside another class.

```
Class A {

    public $property;

    public function __construct( $prop ) {
        $this->property = $prop;

    }
    public function returnValue(){
        return static::$this->property;
    }

}

Class B extends A {

    public static $property_one = 'This is first property';
    public static $property_two = 'This is second property';

}

$B = new B( 'property_one' );
$B->returnValue();
```

I expect to return `This is first property` But the Output is just the name a parameter input in __construct;

When I `print_r( static::$this->property );` the output is just `property_one`

Comment: You are instantiating `A` which never sets or has access to `$property_one`. So the expected result will never be returned

Comment: Sorry I edited post, actually that was instantiating B. sorry for typo.

Comment: You can't return a value in the constructor, `new B` always gives you an object

Comment: I edited post, the goal is I want to get the value of static $property_one from returnValue method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
return static::$this->property;
```

with:

```
return static::${$this->property};
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
<?php
Class A {

    public $property;

    public function __construct( $prop ) {
        $this->property = $prop;
        print static::${$this->property};
    }
}

Class B extends A {

    public static $property_one = 'This is first property';
    public static $property_two = 'This is second property';

}

$B = new B( 'property_one' );
```

(I mean you can access (print,...) the property this way, but the constructor will return an object anyway.)

Comment: This code won't work... it just won't (access a child's static property in the parent's constructor. [Just test this snippet!](http://codepad.org/x3wZ6Trp)

Comment: codepad uses php 5.2 or something similar. Late static binding started to be supported I think from php 5.3. Details: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

1. the static property `$property_one` is declared in class `B`, the `A` class's constructor won't have access to that property, nor can you guarantee this property to be present.
   Granted, since PHP 5.3, late static binding is supported, but that doesn't change the fact that you're never going to be sure that some static property that just *happens* to be called whatever `$this->property` happens to be assigned. What if it's assigned an object? an int, or float?
2. You access a static property like this: `static::$propery` or `self::$property`. Note the `$`! When you write `static::$this->property`, you're expecting this to evaluate to `self::property_one`. You're clearly missing the `$` sign.
   The very least you need is `self::${$this->property}`. Check the PHP manual on variable variables.
3. You're attempting to return a string from a constructor function, that's not possible. A constructor *must*, **must** return an instance of the class. Any return statements that don't will be ignored.

To have access to a static property of a child class in the constructor, you can't but rely on the child's constructor:

```
Class A
{
    public $property;
}

Class B extends A
{
    public static $property_one = 'This is first property';
    public static $property_two = 'This is second property';
    public function __construct( $prop )
    {
        $this->property = $prop;
        print self::${$this->property};
    }
}
$B = new B( 'property_one' );
```

An alternative would be:

```
Class A
{
    public $property;
    public function __constructor($prop)
    {
        $this->property = $prop;
    }
    public function getProp()
    {
        return static::${$this->property};
    }
}

Class B extends A
{
    public static $property_one = 'This is first property';
    public static $property_two = 'This is second property';
}
$B = new B( 'property_one' );
$B->getProp();
```

Comment: actually, I edited post now, but the base code is from Laravel 4. And by static::${$this->property} it is working well.

Comment: @aliA: I was editing my answer, adding code examples and more details... added a second example that fits your now edited question perfectly.